# Order timezone table with STR_TO_DATE with negative values

Tags: mysql, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a timezone table in mysql with three varchars columns: the php timezone code, the GMT offset data for each timezone and a display name like this:

```
Africa/Abidjan, 0:00, (GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik
Africa/Addis_Ababa, +3:00, (GMT+3:00) Nairobi
Africa/Algiers, +1:00, (GMT+1:00) West Central Africa
```

I'm trying to order this table with an `` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`data_gmt`, '%l:%i') `` but I'm having problems with negative offsets.

When selecting the date value of a the offset string, mysql shows me null values for negative and 0:00 values.

```
data_gmt, STR_TO_DATE(`data_gmt`, '%l:%i')
---------------
0:00   NULL
+3:00  03:00:00
+1:00  01:00:00
+2:00  02:00:00
-10:00 NULL
-9:00  NULL
```

Is there a way to order this timezone table from negative time offsets -> 0 -> positive time offsets?

Comment: In your sql_mode there is `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`?

Comment: @AlbertoMoro sql_mode='' but I guess this have no effect with negative dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the hour portion to the left of the `:`, and then `CAST` that to a signed integer for sorting:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data_gmt, ':', 1) AS SIGNED)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bcb9806a6fc278704e78fff237ee4404)